# git diff just the first file (of all unstaged changes)

Tags: git, bash

If I do `git diff`, I'll get the current changes of all unstaged files.

Is there a simpler way to automatically perform `git diff` on just the first listed file (using the built in flags)?

The best I've come up with is:

```
function git_diff_first_unstaged_file() {
    if [[ $(git diff --name-only) ]]; then
      git diff $(git diff --name-only | sed -n '1 p')
    else
      echo "gdf: There are currently no unstaged changes."
    fi
}
alias gdf='git_diff_first_unstaged_file'
```

I'm wondering if there is a `git diff` flag I brushed over that would do this for me.

Comment: There is no flag. Your method is as good as any (more or less: you could make it a bit more efficient by running just the one `git diff --name-only | sed -n 1p`, saving the output in a variable, and then running `git diff` on that saved name only if there was a name).

Comment: I think I could just do `git diff $(git diff --name-only | sed -n 1p)`, but the if statement is nice. Regardless, thanks for confirming my sanity about the potentiality of a flag :)

Comment: I have to ask... why do you want this?

Comment: Before I add code to a commit, I like to git diff all changed files. I could do `git diff` alone, but often times it's just way too much. Rather than doing "git status" and seeing all the files that are unstaged but modified, I can just do this and automatically diff the first one. I made one for `git add` as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Beside git diff --name-only, you also have `git ls-files --modified` that would list you unstaged files (to be used with `| sed -1p` to get the first one).

Don't forget that if you want to start staging diff for the first file, you have the option to simply type:

```
git add -p
```

You will see and will be able to selectively add diffs for the first file (and then the second, at which point you can type <kbd>q</kbd> to quit the interactive staging session)

Comment: Wow! This is fantastic, I didn't know this interactive session existed. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Following the recommendations in the comments, one can add the following alias to `~/.gitconfig` (of project config) in order to make a diff only with the **first unstaged** but **tracked** file:

```
[alias]
    gdf = "! git diff $(git diff --name-only | sed -n 1p)"
```

If you want to make a diff with the **i-th unstaged** but **tracked** file:

```
[alias]
    gdi= "!f() { git diff $(git diff --name-only | sed -n $1p); }; f"
```

`git gdi 3` will show diff of unstaged changes of **third** file (or last file if there are less than 3 files).